# How to clip text in android canvas?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating kids learning application in android.
I created Imageview on which text is displayed and i applied canvas for Imageview so i can able to 
paint on whole canvas. Upto this working fine.

Now my problem is i have to clip the text present in canvas imageview.
I know to clip the region with shapes like Rect , Circle but dont know how to clip the text in android canvas... Also the clipped region must allows me to paint only the clipped region ( not the region other than text view in Imageview .)

Help with some sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Finally i found the solution for my question...

If you want to clip the textview in android you have an method called `getTextPath()`
that will give you the outline of the text which holds the glyph for the text and apply

```
canvas .clipPath(path);
```

Now i can able to clip the text view in android canvas....

Comment: have completed this app can u help me i am working on same apps